# Pulsating color change on svg image

Tags: html, css, svg

I came across this awesome design today: http://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/jPLpLJ

I really like the pulsating color change. On my website I have an .svg logo that I would like to change color like that when I hover over the image. I would like the actual svg to change color, not the background or anything. I really don't need the on-click animation.

Is this possible with css? I know I have the source right there in the codepen but this is a little above my skills.

Note: It doesn't even have to be based on this code. As long as it looks sort of the same it's ok.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canv"></canvas>
<h4>Click For Random Squiggle</h4>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One);
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 10%, 1);
  font-family: 'Poiret One', serif;
}

h4 {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: hsla(255, 255%, 255%, .5);
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var max = 50;
var rad = 200;

var c, $, inc, p;

var c = document.getElementById('canv');
var $ = c.getContext('2d');
var w = c.width = window.innerWidth;
var h = c.height = window.innerHeight;
var u = 0;

var go = function() {
  upd();
  draw();
}

var upd = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      p[i].upd(inc);

    } else {
      p[i].upd(0);
    }
  }
}

var draw = function() {
  u -= .5;
  $.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  $.fillStyle = 'hsla(0,0%,10%,1)';
  $.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

  var xp1 = (p[0].x + p[max - 1].x) / 2;
  var yp1 = (p[0].y + p[max - 1].y) / 2;
 /*
  first beginPath() set is a shadow mimic - 
  a black underlay, which is not necessary but 
  the canvas shadow attr kills the springiness 
  in FF :/ so using this instead for a lil depth. 
  */
  $.beginPath();
  $.strokeStyle = 'hsla(0,0%,5%,.35)';
  $.lineWidth = 26;
  $.moveTo(xp1, yp1);

  for (var i = 0; i < max - 1; i++) {
    var xp = (p[i].x + p[i + 1].x) / 2;
    var yp = (p[i].y + p[i + 1].y) / 2;

    $.quadraticCurveTo(p[i].x - 2, p[i].y + 2, xp, yp);
  }

  $.quadraticCurveTo(p[i].x, p[i].y, xp1, yp1);
  $.closePath();
  $.stroke();

  //this one is the actual color circle. 
  $.beginPath();
  $.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + u + ',100%, 50%,1)';
  $.lineWidth = 20;
  $.moveTo(xp1, yp1);

  for (var i = 0; i < max - 1; i++) {
    var xp = (p[i].x + p[i + 1].x) / 2;
    var yp = (p[i].y + p[i + 1].y) / 2;

    $.quadraticCurveTo(p[i].x, p[i].y, xp, yp);
  }

  $.quadraticCurveTo(p[i].x, p[i].y, xp1, yp1);
  $.closePath();
  $.stroke();


}

var set = function() {

  var rot = 360 / max;
  p = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {

    var pt = new Pt(w / 2, h / 2);
    pt.radii = rot * i;
    pt.rad = rad;
    pt.ready();
    p.push(pt);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  var rnd = (Math.random() * 410) + 10;
  inc = (inc == 0) ? rnd : 0;
}, false);

var ready = function(e) {
  inc = 0;
  set();
  run();
}

var run = function() {
  window.requestAnimFrame(run);
  go();
}
var Pt = function(midX, midY) {
  this.acc = 5;
  this.chng = 1.35;
  this.midX = midX;
  this.midY = midY;
  this.vert = 0;
  this.x, this.y, this.rad, this.radii, this.dia;

  this.ready = function() {
    this.dia = this.rad;
    this.XY();
  }

  this.upd = function(inc) {
    var r = this.dia + inc;
    this.rad = this.getRad(r, this.rad);
    this.XY();
  }

  this.XY = function() {
    var cos = Math.cos(this.radii * (Math.PI / 180)) * this.rad;
    var sin = Math.sin(this.radii * (Math.PI / 180)) * this.rad;

    this.x = cos + this.midX;
    this.y = sin + this.midY;

  }
  this.getRad = function(mv, cur) {
    this.vert = (this.vert + ((mv - cur) / this.acc)) / this.chng;
    return this.vert + cur;
  }
}
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  c.width = w = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = h = window.innerHeight;
  set();
}, false);

ready();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.hue {
  fill: red;
}

.hue:hover {
  animation: pulse 10s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%   { fill: #ff0000 }
  17%  { fill: #ffff00 }
  33%  { fill: #00ff00 }
  50%  { fill: #00ffff }
  67%  { fill: #0000ff }
  83%  { fill: #ff00ff }
  100% { fill: #ff0000 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0%   { fill: #ff0000 }
  17%  { fill: #ffff00 }
  33%  { fill: #00ff00 }
  50%  { fill: #00ffff }
  67%  { fill: #0000ff }
  83%  { fill: #ff00ff }
  100% { fill: #ff0000 }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="70" class="hue"/>
</svg>
```

This should work in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Paul LeBeau you are a hero! This is spot on exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: The SVG I have is fairly complex. Is there any way I can link to the image instead (like img src) or something?

Comment: CSS doesn't apply across document boundaries.  But the animation should work if you put the CSS in the SVG file.  You can use a `<style>` element for that, Note that the CSS has to go in the SVG file itself. You can't link to a CSS file from the SVG if you are using an `<img>` to reference the SVG.